# Option to hide posts from top network posts

Tags: feature-request

It would be helpful to be able to hid certain posts from your "top network posts" section. Sure, someone could visit my profile on other sites, but they are much less likely to see some questions/answers if they aren't on my profile page.

Comment: That's what the hide communities feature is for.

Comment: @Oded: Actually, that works really well